# Most powerful test - hypothesis

Tags: probability, statistics, density-function, hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood

sample of size n = 1 from p.d.f.

$f(x| \theta) = 1 +\theta^2 (0.5-x)$ if $0<x<1, 0 $ o/w

where $-1 ≤ \theta ≤ 1$

> Derive the MP test for testing $$H_0 : \theta = 0$$ $$H_A : \theta = \theta_1$$ at level significance
> $\alpha$

> Derive the power of this test at $\theta = \theta_1$

So we have been given this question but only covered it briefly so was wondering if someone could help please.

My thoughts are as follows:
The first part I'm not too sure how to do, it is a bit challenging but i have thoughts of using likelihood ratio test?

The second part we just use the definition maybe?

I am pretty new to this topic but would like to get better + if someone could help it would be really helpful, thank you :)

Comment: given that the two hypothesis are both simple, you can use Neyman Pearson's lemma but the critical region changes if $\theta_1$ is greater o less than 0. Have you information about $\theta_1$?

Comment: @tommik if you dont mind could you provide a bit of an extra solution to this, it is a bit challenging this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Neyman Pearson's lemma  you get

$$\frac{L(\theta_0|\mathbf{x})}{L(\theta_1|\mathbf{x})}\leq c$$

which leads immediately to the following critial region

$$x\leq c^*$$

In fact, simply substituting, you get

$$\frac{1}{1+\theta_1^2(0.5-x)}\leq c$$

that is very easy to be solved w.r.t. $x$ finding

$$x\leq c^*$$

In the constant $c^*$ all the expressions not depending on $x$ are included...but it is not a problem as $c^*$ for you is only a point at which evaluate an integral...

thus you can reject $H_0$ if

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq c^*|\theta=0]=\alpha$$

that is

$$\int_0^{c^*} dx=\alpha$$

$$c^*=\alpha$$

to get the power, simply using the definition  you get

$$\mathbb{P}[X\leq \alpha|\theta=\theta_1]=\gamma$$

that is

$$\int_0^{\alpha}[1+\theta^2(0.5-x)]dx=\left(1+\frac{\theta^2}{2}\right)\alpha-\frac{\theta^2}{2}\alpha^2$$

As you can see (fixing a certain $\alpha$) the power increases as $|\theta|$ increases...

this is the graphic of your power function w.r.t. $\theta$

(for this graphic I set $\alpha=5\%$)

[image]

Comment: $\frac{L(\theta_0|\mathbf{x})}{L(\theta_1|\mathbf{x})}\leq c$ how did you work that out to get the next line $x ≤ c$

Comment: f(x | 0 ) = 1 , but f(x | $\theta_1$) = ? I'm not too sure how to do that part

Comment: solve the ratio w.r.t. $x$

Comment: could you show that please, im still stuck (so sorry about so many questions) :(

Comment: so sorry, i always forget to do that - thank you - done

Comment: added some details...hope now it is clear

Comment: thank you v much :)